# GridView doesn't show results with First() query extension

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, controls

I am using LINQ-to-Entities and have loaded up a Northwind Database (with LazyLoading=true).

```
var db = new NorthwindEntities();
var result = db.Orders.Where(x => x.CustomerID == "ANATR").First();        
DataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

The above code doesn't show up any items (one in this particular case) in the DataGridView. What am I doing wrong?

(If I remove the 'First()' it works fine and gives me several items)

Comment: Are you sure there's a CustomerID == "ANATR"?

Comment: Does it work if you do `.Take(1)` instead? I'm wondering if it is due to the difference in what type `result` is.

Comment: Yes, I am sure there is because if I remove the 'First' it shows me results

Comment: Chris, yes! Take(1) works, but why First doesn't return any results?

Comment: A grid seems an unusual choice of control for displaying a single item :)

Answer (score 4):

The result is not a collection, that's why, you can not list it. First is a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is actually a single object not a collection of objects.

Try adding the result to an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

var db = new NorthwindEntities();
var result = db.Orders.Where(x => x.CustomerID == "ANATR").First();
DataGridView1.DataSource = result;

since `result` isn't a `Collection` this won't work you can use

```
var results =Enumerable.Repeat(result, 1);
```

To create single item in a list to do this or also

```
var results = new List<Order>() { result };
```

Will also work

And then bind to `results` instead of result